# Termination characters rs232 simulink

Tags: serial-port, simulink

I have a simulink model that tries to receive data through a rs232 block. Unfortunately there is no way I can specify termination characters with the blocks I use. Is there a way to make the stream know it has reached the end of a byte stream?

For example: I have an external application send a continuous stream of 5 byte messages where the last two are termination characters to mark the end of the message (0xFF & 0xFE for example, I also control the other side so I can use anything I want). I want my simulink application to know when the first 5 byte message stops and the second 5 byte message starts. If I do not use these termination characters my simulink model has no way to tell where the first message ends and the second one starts... (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Do you mean NULL(0x00) by termination character? Is it used in the data transferred?can's you send the NULL byte as the termination character to find the end of the block? It's the way strings are defined and a string is always ended with a 0x00 as the termination byte

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Couldn't you just implement a matlab function block which does `hex2dec`? When there is the termination byte `hex2dec('FF')` the block would return 255, which is the maximum. So you could just compare it or use a zero-crossing detection or whatever, to get a puls/flag when the new message starts?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! But what would this look like? I'm having trouble using variable size vectors in my simulink model.

Comment: It's just hard to help you, could you create a minimal example which reproduces your problem? It already would help if you post the input stream here, exactly how you get it into simulink. And then what you want to achieve, though I can imagine that. Are you converting the input to something non-hex anyway? This seems to me the right starting point.